# Display Post Format as a String

Tags: post-formats

I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I can't find an answer.  I just want to display (in the loop) what post format a post is in. I'm trying to avoid using a bunch of if / else if conditions.

I'm not trying to restyle the post based on format, just display "Gallery" or "Quote" or whatever the current post format is, given they are enabled for my current theme.

Comment: Where did you set post format you want to know?

Comment: Check this out

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
?>
```

**EDIT**

Note, if you want a fail-safe output, try this:

```
<?php
if ( get_post_format() ) {
    echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
} else {
    ehco 'Standard';
}
?>
```

Or, if you want to store it in a variable:

```
<?php
$post_format_string = ( get_post_format() ? get_post_format_string( get_post_format() ) : 'Standard' );
// echo the result
echo $post_format_string;
?>
```

Codex ref: [get_post_format()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format), [get_post_format_string()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format_string)